# How can Flyway respect version control and the SDLC?

Tags: database, migration, flyway, sdlc

We are thinking of integrating [*Flyway*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyway_(software)) in our application but are concerned about the way it maintains its own versions and how that works with the [Software development life cycle (SDLC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_development_process).

In essence our problem with the approach is that you are maintaining a set of SQL scripts separated by version in the file name instead of maintaining a trunk in version control and releasing/tagging that trunk as a specific version. With Flyway a developer could go back and change an old migration script that relates to a released version of your application and break a version you've already integrated/tested/staged and shipped to a production environment.

What we are considering doing is maintaining the SQL migrations in a project under version control (i.e. my-app-db/trunk/migration.sql) and releasing/tagging from there when a SQL developer is stating it is ready as a release (V1.0.0__blah.sql). The trunk/migration.sql is then wiped out so that the next 1.0.1 or 1.1.0 script can be developed and tagged. A wrapper script will then export the SQL files from the tags, call Flyway with that directory to perform the migration, and clean up the export.

Does this seem like a valid point/approach? Will Flyway ever support something like version control?

Comment: FYI, as of version 4.2 if not earlier, the [`Validate`](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/command/validate) command, as I understand it, verifies the existing scripts to see that they have not been altered or deleted since being applied. Apparently this is done by checking the [checksum calculated and recorded](https://flywaydb.org/getstarted/how) for each migration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flyway 3.0 will open APIs that will make it possible for end users to extend it in this direction. Out of the box support for SCM integration is currently not on the agenda.